# Finding the mean of numbers in a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay so I want to calculate the mean of an array based on users input. I have a textbox where users will enter numbers and the numbers will be split by a comma. So the text box will look like 23, 11, 24, 45 etc. As you see below I currently have it pulling from hard coded array for now.

Front End Code

```
<p>Please enter your numbers within the textbox provided</p>

<asp:TextBox ID="userInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<div>
    <p>The mean is:</p>

    <asp:TextBox ID="meanTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="calculateResults" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="calculateResults_Click" />
```

Back End Code of Button

```
protected void calculateResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] numbers = { 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 };

    double mean = numbers.Average();

    meanTextBox.Text = mean.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto probably he doesn't know that mean = average/count or doesn't know how to make int[] from TextBox.Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string input from the checkbox to the `string[]`. This can be done with splitting by `' '`. After that you need to convert the `string[]` to `int[]` and in last step is to calculate the mean value which is Average/NumberOfElements.

```
    decimal valueOf = 0;

    var myInts = Array.ConvertAll(userInput.Text.Split(' '), s => decimal.TryParse(s, out valueOf) ? valueOf: 0);

    var mean= myInts.Average() / myInts.Count();
    meanTextBox.Text = mean.ToString();
```

Here we go.